# Mongo db failed to start in centos 07

Tags: mongodb, centos

I followed this link [1] to install mongo db under centos 07, the data base started normally but then I don't know what happen it did not want to start again giving me this error:

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl start mongod
Job for mongod.service failed. See 'systemctl status mongod.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status mongod.service -l
mongod.service - SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since mer. 2015-08-05 17:13:12 CEST; 24s ago
  Process: 2872 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

août 05 17:13:12 localhost systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database....
août 05 17:13:12 localhost runuser[2878]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user mongod by (uid=0)
août 05 17:13:12 localhost mongod[2872]: Starting mongod: [ÉCHOUÉ]
août 05 17:13:12 localhost systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
août 05 17:13:12 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database..
août 05 17:13:12 localhost systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
```

I configured SELinux to "enforcing" and I enabled the access to the port 27017 using

```
semanage port -a -t mongod_port_t -p tcp 27017
```

I can start the data base using this command:

```
[root@localhost ~]# sudo -u root /usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 3058
child process started successfully, parent exiting
```

But still can't start it as a service :(
Any ideas of what I have missed?

Thanks in advance for your help!

[1] http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/